# turtle drawing background change raw_input python 2.7

Tags: python

I want the user to enter a color name to set the background of the turtle window which is a drawing program, I forgoten how to do it?

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()


color = raw_input('enter background color') 

color ??????? wn.bgcolor('')      # set the window background color




tess = turtle.Turtle()
tess.color("blue")              # make tess blue
tess.pensize(3)                 # set the width of her pen

tess.forward(50)
tess.left(120)
tess.forward(50)

wn.exitonclick()                # wait for a user click on the canvas
```

Comment: I remember there was some way of adding stuff to tuples? like some kind of % or & thing that would ad stuff to a () or something?

Answer (score 0):

Just give the string to the `bgcolor()` method:

```
...
color = raw_input('Enter background color: ')
wn.bgcolor(color)
tess = turtle.Turtle()
....
```

Comment: now i need to convert pen size to an int? I appear to be doing something wrong, 


pen = int(raw_input('Enter pen: '))

Comment: It should work, are you getting any error? or it just doesn't work?